# How to Cross Compile Library Using Standalone NDK toolchain

Tags: android, makefile, arm

So I am trying to cross compile Box2D using the source and I would like to compile for Android on my Mac. I can run...

> ../box2d-read-only/Box2D/Build/gmake$ make

And this works fine, now how do I update the GCC version I am using to that of the ARM processor. I tried the following...

> make CC="/tmp/my-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"

This seems to work, but is it really? I am new to gcc and I have a hunch it is using the Mac x86 (or whatever) gcc. Is there a good way to test if it is compiled for the proper arch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer in the documentation, this seems to work....

> export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH
>
> export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc   # or export CC=clang
>
> export CXX=arm-linux-androideabi-g++  # or export CXX=clang++
>
> make

Still working on confirming it though....

Found in documentation.